# Does cn1 google analytics support GA4

Tags: codenameone

I have questions to use cn1's google analytics support.

Does cn1 google analytics support GA4?

How do I set the data stream of resources on Google Analytics for my cn1 app? Which options to choose? iOS, Android, or web?

How do I set the domain if I should choose web for my cn1 app?

Answer (score 0):

No we didn't integrate it. This isn't supported at this time.

Comment: Would you consider supporting GA4?
This can let me know how users engaged with my app.
Thank you.

Comment: This depends on the scale of demand for that feature and so far it doesn't seem like there's enough demand for that.

Comment: Any ideas I can rack the usage of my cn1 app? Should I build a server and send logs from my cn1 app to it? Any recommendation?

Comment: Try working with Mixpanel, Segment, Amplitude, PostHog or Matomo. One of them might have a REST API you can work with for tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I will add that we are looking for the option to integrate GA4 as well. It would be great if there was a way to integrate this into an app. It would allow for increased growth based on feedback we could gather from the analytics.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).